# struct.error: repeat count given without format specifier

Tags: python, struct, network-programming

**DETAILS**

I'm trying to understand a network program that implements the selective repeat (SR) protocol. Here's the process:

1. Run *server.py* by specifying a port number, protocol, and window size
2. Run *client.py* by specifying a filename, port number, and number of packets

When I run *client.py,* I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "client.py", line 238, in <module>
cs = pack('IHH' + str(len(data)), 's', seqNum, header, data)
struct.error: repeat count given without format specifier
```

Here's the block of code that's tripping me up:

```
while not sendComplete:
    toSend = lastInWindow + 1
    data = GetMessage()
    header = int('0101010101010101', 2)
    cs = pack('IHH' + str(len(data)), 's', seqNum, header, data)
    checksum = CalculateChecksum(cs)

packet = pack('IHH' + str(len(data)) + 's', seqNum, checksum, header, data)
    if toSend < windowSize:
        sendBuffer.append(packet)
        timeoutTimers.append(TIMEOUT)
    else:
        sendBuffer[toSend % windowSize] = packet
        timeoutTimers[toSend % windowSize] = TIMEOUT
```

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

I've taken several steps to fix this issue, all of which have failed (obviously), and I'm not sure if I'm getting closer to the light or heading deeper into the woods.

1. Using *struct.pack(fmt=...)* as suggested by PyCharm
2. Per PyCharm's advice, I concatenate the arguments using a +
3. I run the program again and receive a *TypeError: must be str, not int* error, which I attempt to fix by implementing *str(seqNum), str(header), etc.*
4. Finally, I get a *TypeError: pack() takes no keyword arguments* response and throw in the towel.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain what's going on here and how I can get this program up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you made a typo on the `pack` format function, instead of (',' instead of '+'):

`pack('IHH' + str(len(data)), 's', seqNum, header, data)`

it should be:

`pack('IHH' + str(len(data)) + 's', seqNum, header, data)`

That happens because every time there is a number on the byte format, it repeats the next character number times. So a `4h` will become `hhhh`. The wrong line ended on a number(eg: "IHH6"), so it didn't know what to repeat.

Also, you are packing 4 "things", you should add another argument to the pack function:

```
pack('IHH' + str(len(data)) + 's', seqNum, header, data, missing_var)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I made the following change: cs = pack('IH' + str(len(data)), 's', seqNum, header, data), and I'm told "struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object". I changed it to bytes using bytes('s', 'utf-8), but then I'm told it's supposed to be a str. I change it to str('s'), and then it says 's' must be a bytes object. Why does it go back-and-forth like this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the errors you are talking about, eg: https://repl.it/repls/BumpyMushyDaemons